# Call JSON after user has made the filter

Tags: angularjs, json, drupal

I have an extremely large JSON (5000 keys with 5 values each), and i want to know if there's a better way to improve performance of this one. For example I'm using AngularJS with a Backend in Drupal 7.

My View

```
  <ul class="list-group border-0">
                 <form class="form-inline m-3">
                    <div class="col-sm p-0 float-left w-50">
                      <label class="col-form-label text-primary lead form-group" for="inputsm" for="name" for="inlineFormInput">Year: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm p-0 float-left w-50">
                      <input class="form-control" ng-model="searchYear"/> 
                    </div>
                 </form> //I have more filters than this one...
                  <li class="list-group-item border-0" ng-repeat="item in filterData = (informes | filter:{year: searchYear}) | limitTo:10:10*(currentPage-1)">
                     <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="informes">
                          <a href="#!/node-informes" ng-value="{{item.nid}}">
                            <p class="text-left">
                               <p ng-click="nodeID(item)">{{item.title}}</p>
                            </p>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>      
              </ul>
```

And the JS

```
    informes.factory('InformesFtry', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
      getAll: function () {
        return $http.get('https://myjsonurl/json');
      }
   };
}]); 

 informes.controller('InformesCtrl', ['drupal', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'InformesFtry', '$localStorage', function(drupal, $rootScope, $scope, $http, InformesFtry, $localStorage) {

    InformesFtry.getAll().success(function(rows) {
        $scope.informes = (rows, function(items) {
            return rows.nodes;
        })();
        $scope.output();
    });

    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $scope.totalItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

    $scope.output = function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.loaded = true;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.informes.length;
        $scope.viewby = 10;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
        $scope.displayItems = $scope.informes.slice(0, 10);
        var currentPage = $scope.currentPage;

        $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
            $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
        }

        $scope.pageChanged = function() {
            var startPos = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * 10;
            $scope.displayItems = $scope.informes.slice(startPos, startPos + 10);
        };

    }

    $scope.nodeID = function(item) {
     $localStorage.nid = item.nid;
     console.log("nodeID");
    }
}]);
```

I tried from my Backend to separate those files and iterate from the controller, but it's better for performance to search in JSON after the query has been made from the view, like an inverse from what i'm doing. Search everywhere but i couldn't get to a possible resolution.

I thought about using json after the query from the view has been made.

I don't know how to achieve that. Separating the files will give me the same result unless there's some way to make the filter before calling JSON. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is absolutely ways to make this more performant.  You can improve the performance by moving your filter logic from your `ng-repeat` to the controller.  Then update the list of item you want to repeat over in your controller.  Here is a great article that talks about this exactly.

https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/

Brief Explanation as to why this helps is that your `ng-repeat` will continually be processed for changes on digest cycles even if the values around it never changed, this means its filtering those 5,000 records each time.  You can move your filtering logic to the controller and then trigger when you update your list by using `ng-change` on your filters (like your year input).

So implementing that would look like the following:

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.updateData = function(){
    var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.informes, {'year': $scope.searchYear});
    filteredData = $filter('limitTo')(filteredData, 10, (10 * (currentPage - 1)));
    $scope.filteredData = filteredData;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Your Inputs should have ng-change -->
<input class="form-control" ng-model="searchYear" ng-change="updateData()"/> 

<!-- Remove filters from html and loop over your filtered list -->
<li class="list-group-item border-0" ng-repeat="item in filteredData">
```

Edit: Added additional explanation & example code changes.

Comment: It will work after the first call has been made, for example when i start up it calls the json file for first time and this is when i have the problem, i mean loading 5000+ records could take more than 1 minute, 45 seconds sometime. The solution you posted is correct but it will be when the 5000+ records has been loaded.

Comment: Instead you can move the filtering and pagination to the server side.  Then use the same updateFilter function to fetch a new filtered set of data from your server.  For the initial call, even with no filters set, the data can be pagination so you only return 10 or so entries.  Should be quick.

Comment: Yea i think is better the way you said. So the user don't have to wait a lot of time, thanks I will fb after that

Comment: It worked!!! What i did is updating my code with the help you provided and now the pager works and load every registry i'm looking for without waiting. Now I'm trying to figure how is the filter url syntax. I will UPDATE after done. Thanks!!!